# how to call the function from a file

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

hi I need help with the problem as stated in the title! I keep my python source code in a file named darren.py and I want to use a function, compute_mean, which is defined in my .py file. how can I call and use this function in python?

do I type this?

```
from darren.py import compute_mean
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code?

Comment: I haven't run it yet as I'm unsure if that would be the right way to import my codes

Comment: Try it in a test file, see what happens :). Nothing harmful about an error message

Answer (score 2):

When you import a module, you must remove the extension `.py` such as below.

```
from darren import compute_mean
```

Comment: :: Hi @darrenbarren if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.